# How to read string with spaces, until a '\r'?

Tags: c++

I want to read a long string, and split it into smaller ones, where each new row of the big string is an entry for the smaller ones. However, I only want it to break at '\r', and not at spaces.
This is a sample code of what I'm doing right now:

```
std::vector<std::string> m_list;
std::ifstream input("data.txt");
std::string str;
std::getline(input, str);
std::istringstream iss(str);
std::string temp;
while (iss >> temp)
{
    m_list.push_back(temp);
}
```

However, this code breaks the string upon encountering spaces, as well.

Comment: `std::getline` seems to be on the menu. An actual example of your input and expected output will speak louder than trying to describe it, however. When you say `'/r'` do you mean an actual for-slash and 'r' (two characters), or do you mean a carriage return? Regardless, `std::getline` can still be used for breaking up strings on things besides just newlines.

Comment: I'm still learning programming. I suspect that I can add some stuff to the arguments of getline, but I don't know what are they supposed to be. And that's why I'm asking here. I checked multiple other threads, but couldn't find the exact answer to my question.
Ah, damn, I meant `'\r'` as in new line.

Comment: You almost never should be dealing with `'\r'`.  Text-mode streams automatically convert the platform's newline sequences into `'\n'`. (And no modern platforms use `'\r'` by itself for a newline sequence anyway.)

Comment: As I said, I'm still learning programming. There are a lot of things I don't know. I googled "char for a new line" or something like that, and it told me it's `'\r'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where definitely on the right path, you actually just need to skip the direct string stream operation. This should work fine:

```
    std::vector<std::string> m_list;
    std::ifstream input("data.txt");
    std::string str;        
    
    while (std::getline(input, str, '\r'))
    {
        m_list.push_back(str);
    }
```

Comment: This does not break at new lines `'\r'` tho. It just lumps the whole thing into a single string. Okay, after the edit, it works!